# How to query the child elements of a particular parent element

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am developing asp.net mobile application. I am using the XML as a database. I am using the following part of the XML file to query the data by using the LINQ to XML.

```
<USER-INTERFACE-DEFINITION>
      <MIMICS>
       <MIMIC ID="1" NAME="Home">
        <SECTIONS>
         <SECTION ID ="1" NAME="System Health" CONTROL-TYPE="Button">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
         <SECTION ID ="2" NAME="Network Status" CONTROL-TYPE="Button">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
         <SECTION ID ="3" NAME="ESD Status" CONTROL-TYPE="Button">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
         <SECTION ID ="4" NAME="DWPLEM" CONTROL-TYPE="Button">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
         <SECTION ID="5" NAME="Manifolds" CONTROL-TYPE="Drowpdown">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
         <SECTION ID ="6" NAME="Wells" CONTROL-TYPE="Drowpdown">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
         <SECTION ID ="7" NAME="Alarms" CONTROL-TYPE="Button">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
         <SECTION ID ="8" NAME="House Keeping" CONTROL-TYPE="Button">
          <DATAITEMS>
          </DATAITEMS>
         </SECTION>
        </SECTIONS>
       </MIMIC>
    </USER-INTERFACE-DEFINITION>
```

In the above XML file I want to retrive the "NAME" attribute of the SECTION node with the condition MIMIC ID="1". I dont want to modify my existing XML file. I have the server collection of node  with simialr elements as the above XML file. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Comment: There are *lots* of SECTION nodes under the MIMIC node with ID=1. Which one are you after?

Comment: @Jon: thanks, I changed my answer to reflect that :)

Comment: I want to retrieve "NAME", "ID" & CONTROL-TYPE" attribute of all the SECTION node with the condition MIMIC ID=1

Comment: that's a new request and different from *"I want to retrive the "NAME" attribute..."*. What Jon means, there are many nodes that satisfy your condition, are you sure that is correct?

Comment: yes it means there are many nodes that satisfy the given condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("your xml");
var q = from m in xml.Descendants("MIMIC")
        where (int)m.Attribute("ID") == 1
        from s in m.Descendants("SECTION")
        select (string)s.Attribute("NAME");

foreach ( var name in q ) {
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

I have tested the above in LINQPad and it does indeed produce:

```
    System Health
    Network Status
    ESD Status
    DWPLEM
    Manifolds
    Wells
    Alarms
    House Keeping
```

Comment: I actually hate LINQ to XML because the equivalent XPath is almost always cleaner. But since the OP asked for LINQ to XML I figured I'd comply. :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If you please tell me how to retrieve all the elements - ID ="1" NAME="System Health" CONTROL-TYPE="Button" at a time then it would help me a lot.

Comment: Instead of select (string)s.Attribute("NAME") just change it to select s. That will get you the entire SECTION node.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like (not LINQ, but you can use it with LINQ if you like):

```
var nodes = myXmlDoc.SelectNodes("/USER-INTERFACE-DEFINITION/MIMICS/MIMIC[@ID='1']/SECTION/@NAME");
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    string name = node.Value;
    // do something with each name
}
```

(assuming myXmlDoc is created using `.Load(yourXmlFileHer)` and assuming `USER-INTERFACE-DEFINITION` is the root of the XML, otherwise, start with `//` instead)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it my best try but you might wan't to supply the relevant part of the XML to make it easier for us. Does the section have this condition or the name. At least I might get you started.

Let's start with this:

```
var name = xml.Descendants<SECTION>.Where(s => s.id == 1).GetFirstChild<NAME>();
```

Hoping I'm not way off, if that's the case I guess someone will suply a better answer.

Ok after seeing your XML I was some way off. Also when I think about it Descendants probably woudln't work.

Comment: You're trying to use names as generic type arguments... you mean `Descendants("SECTION")` etc.

Comment: Yeah just noted that in my edit, also didn't see the XML before my answer so this is some way off.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML is held in a string called `xml` then:

```
var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
var results = root
            .Descendants("MIMIC")
            .Where( e => e.Attribute("ID").Value == "1" )
            .SelectMany(e => e.Descendants("SECTION").Attributes("NAME" ) ) ;
```